# how to reload page when there is change in css?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, gulp, gulp-watch

I try to reload my page when There is an change in **scss** file.I download browser syn plugin and try to use this but it is not reloading when there is change in scss file .

Actually what I what

if there is change is scss file it should do the following steps

- Convert the scss file to css file.
- convert the css file to css.min file.
- then reload the page .

I am able to convert sass to css file ,css to css.min file and also able to make server but it is not reloading while change in scss file .

here is my **gulp.js**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
//require sass package
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var minifyCss = require('gulp-minify-css');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
var browerSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var reload=browerSync.reload;

gulp.task('serve',['minify-css'],function(){
    browerSync.init({
        server:'./'
    })

   // gulp.watch('scss/*.scss',['minify-css']);
    gulp.watch('scss/*.scss').on('change',reload)


})




// Compile Our Sass
gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return gulp.src('scss/*.scss')
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('css'));
});
// css miifilcation
gulp.task('minify-css',['sass'], function () {
    return gulp.src('css/*.css')
        .pipe(minifyCss())
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

// js minifiction
gulp.task('compress', function() {
    return gulp.src('app/**/*.js')
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('jdist'));
});

//concatination of js files

gulp.task('scripts',['compress'], function() {
    return gulp.src('jdist/**/*.js')
        .pipe(concat('all.js'))
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'));
});


// Watch Files For Changes
gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch('scss/*.scss', ['sass','minify-css']);
    gulp.watch('app/**/*.js', ['compress','scripts']);

});

gulp.task('default', ['serve']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use livereload,
https://github.com/livereload/livereload-plugins ,
http://livereload.com/

Using this tool browser will reload once you update your html/css/javascript files